# A lot of images in tableView

Tags: ios, image, tableview, collectionview

I have tableView with collectionView inside. 
I have ~500+ images in collectionView.

Firstly I use paths and load images in collectionView from paths from collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: . But it was slow and I begin to fill collectionView with UIImages from array. It became faster but it must be more faster. How can I accelerate it?

Comment: dont load all at one instead load chunk by chunk, for example load on scroll or place a uibutton at bottom of screen view, then on click add more

Comment: Are you load image from server or you used local images?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [FastImageCache](https://github.com/path/FastImageCache), a fast loading image cache. The requirements/assumptions don't fit every use case, but from your problem statement it could work for you.